# Panel from dataframe dict, ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, panel

I am trying to create a panel object from stacked panel data. See code below. I have a set of 8000 stocks and I try to create the panel such that the stocks are on items axis. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('C:Stocks.csv', index_col='date')
identifier = pd.unique(data['CUSIP'])

dict_dfStocks={}
for k in identifier :
    print(k)
    dict_dfStocks[k]= data[data.CUSIP==k]

pd.Panel.from_dict(dict_dfStocks)
```

However, I get the following error:

> "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Thank you!